# Linq query returns null when using the EF core relationship

Tags: c#, relationship, ef-core-2.0

Two class defined as below :

```
class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
class Post
{
     public int PostId { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }

     public int BlogId { get; set; }
     public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

and when using this Linq query :
`var posts = context.Blog.FirstOrDefault(e => e.BlogId == 1).Posts.ToList();`
an exception is thrown which says value cannot be null.
And in result view the Posts column of the Blog Table for each row is empty.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: Are you running this against actual database provider (like localdb), in memory database or some other provider ? Can you share more of the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: Also Blog table can not have a Posts column. That is not how usually databases work and definitely not how EF core ORM works. So maybe it was "Post column" instead of "Posts column" or "Blog Array" instead of "Blog Table"?

Comment: @JoshuaWebb is probably right. If lazy loading is not enabled on your db context you will be getting errors while trying to do this without `Include()` statement.... but I would expect a different error message...

Comment: Thanks alot guys i've got the idea from your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite query
`FirstOrDefault` causes querying db and therefore relationship might not be loaded

Therefore do projection before querying:

```
var posts = context.Blog
                   .SelectMany(b => b.Posts)
                   .Where(p => p.BlogId == 1)
                   .ToList();
```

Other alternative is to use `.Include()`

```
var posts = context.Blog
                   .Include(b => b.Posts)
                   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.BlogId == 1)
                   ?.Posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you can include select clause here. Calling FirstOrDefault() on your query will return the first result of the query or the default value for the type (most likely null in this case).
try out this

```
var posts =
    (from e in context.Blog
    where e.BlogId == 1
    select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is no lazy loading you need to include the entity Posts

```
var blog = context.Blog
                   .Include(b => b.Posts)
                   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.BlogId == 1);
```

as you are doing Firtordefault you need to check for null

```
if(blog != null)
{
  ... do your work
}
```